# ggplot2 version 3.2.0 and bayesAB plots conflict

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is a simple Bayesian comparison between two groups using the `bayesAB` package:

```
library(bayesAB)

A_binom <- rbinom(100, 1, .5)
B_binom <- rbinom(100, 1, .6)

AB1 <- bayesTest(A_binom, B_binom,
                 priors = c('alpha' = 1, 'beta' = 1),
                 distribution = 'bernoulli')
plot(AB1)
```

and using the previous version of `ggplot2` (3.1.1) the process used to return the expected plots, as described and shown here: https://frankportman.github.io/bayesAB/reference/bayesTest.html .

However, after updating to `ggplot2` (3.2.0) I get the following error after running `plot(AB1)`:

> Error: Either ymin or ymax must be given as an aesthetic.

After checking a bit more using `p = plot(AB1)` to focus on each plot separately I saw that `p$posteriors` and 
`p$samples` work as expected and the issue has to do with `p$priors`. There's also a similar issue with commands like `plotBeta(6,4)`, `plotGamma(1,1)`, etc. from the same package (`bayesAB`).

Is there a way to solve this using `ggplot2` 3.2.0?

Comment: Author of bayesAB here: as of July 2nd 2019 a fix is on CRAN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is due to changes in the code for `geom_ribbon` (see the 'breaking changes' section of the [CRAN news file for 3.2.0](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/news/news.html)).

The ggplot2 team has already alerted the package author via [bayesAB's GH issues page](https://github.com/FrankPortman/bayesAB/issues/33), so hopefully the package can be updated soon to address this.

Until then, one quick workaround is to modify the underlying problematic code, in the unexported `plotDist_` function, by running `trace(bayesAB:::plotDist_, edit=TRUE)` at the start of your R session, and modifying the following line of code.

Original:

```
function (support, hseq, dist, params) 
{
    discretes <- c("Poisson")
    ribbon_or_bar <- ggplot2::geom_ribbon(ymin = 0, 
        ymax = hseq, # <- modify this line
        size = 2, color = I("lightblue"), fill = "lightgreen", 
        alpha = 0.25)
    # ... omitted
}
```

Modified:

```
function (support, hseq, dist, params) 
{
    discretes <- c("Poisson")
    ribbon_or_bar <- ggplot2::geom_ribbon(ymin = 0, 
        mapping = ggplot2::aes(ymax = hseq), # new version, with ymax placed inside aes()
        size = 2, color = I("lightblue"), fill = "lightgreen", 
        alpha = 0.25)
    # ... omitted
}
```

`plot(AB1)` should work as before after the change. Below is the plot corresponding to `p$priors`:

[image: plot]

`plotBeta(6,4)`:

[image: plot2]

`plotGamma(1,1)`:

[image: plot3]